# What's an adjective for "financially motivated"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I need an adjective for the term "financially motivated." The word I'm looking for isn't exactly greedy or rapacious. Although it can have connotations like that, the word needs to directly mean something more similar to "he does his job well if there's money (or perhaps just incentive) on the line."

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Are you looking to describe a person or an organization?

Comment: A person @TimGrant

Comment: Hi Kevin, it's considered good form on Stack to edit your question without clarifications. The idea is that readers shouldn't need to read the comments to understand the question. Take the tour when you can for more pointers: https://english.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

The word you are probably seeking is ***mercenary***, which exists both as noun and adjective.

It tends to carry negative connotations and is applied more specifically than in any other context to soldiers of fortune, who fight, not for a national flag, but for financial reward. indeed that is how the term is applied as a noun. ***A mercenary*** is such a soldier.

Its etymology is from Latin via Norman French, though the earliest example the OED has, is from Chaucer:

> ▸ c1387–95   Chaucer Canterbury Tales Prol. 514   He [sc. the parson]
>   was a shepherde and noght a mercenarye [v.r. mersenarye].

The full range of OED entries for ***mercenary***, without the multiple examples under each sense,  is as follows:

> A.
>    1. A person who works merely for money or other material reward; a hireling. In later use (probably influenced also by sense A. 2): a
>   person whose actions are motivated primarily by personal gain, often
>   at the expense of ethics. c1387–95—1998
>
> 2.a. A person who receives payment for his or her services. Chiefly and now only: spec. a soldier paid to serve in a foreign army or other
>   military organization. 1523—1974
>       b. In extended use, with modifying word. 1861—1987
>
> B. adj.  1 a. Of a person, organization, etc.: working or acting
>   merely for money or other material reward; motivated by self-interest;
>   materialistic. 1532—1997    b. Of conduct, a course of action, etc.,
>   or its motivation: characterized by self-interest or the pursuit of
>   personal gain; prompted by the desire for money or other material
>   reward; undertaken only for personal gain. 1532—1990
>
> 2. a. Hired, serving for wages. Now: spec. designating a soldier paid to serve in a foreign army or other military organization; (of an
>      army) composed of such soldiers. 1569—1974    †b. Salaried,
>      stipendiary; profit-making. Obsolete. 1656—1782
>
>    3. Of or belonging to a mercenary. a1616—1922

Answer (score 2):

**avaricious**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/avaricious)

adj

> immoderately desirous of wealth or gain; greedy.

As in:

> When you put the most **avaricious** in charge, they use the tools of
>   governance to further enrich themselves. New York Times Dec 7, 2018

Answer (score 1):

You might describe such a person or their worldview as **transactional**.

In other words, this person makes an effort in a certain context because compensation is offered. Either broadly or in a certain situation, they might interpret their own and others' actions and expectations through the lens of a balance sheet—effort for its own sake is neither extended nor expected.

The term is not especially complimentary but is far less pejorative than the alternatives "greedy," "desperate," ""avaricious," "rapacious," "materialistic," or "mercenary" (!). It includes anyone who expects to receive a paycheck from their employer, for example. One could frame the behavior in a positive way by saying that the person is  businesslike or practical in expecting a suitably compensated, mutually fulfilling professional relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could say that one is "economically ambitious". To get it into one word you could say "greedy" but this implies a sense of self-centered focus without regard to others.

A term we use to describe effective salespeople is often "coin-operated"

Answer (score 0):

*Financially motivated* typically refers to cash-strapped sellers and suggests you can get what ever they are selling at a bargain. In this sense, *desperate* is about right. But you seem to be looking for something like a person who's *all business*.

I suggest the idiom *sees dollar signs* - he does his job well when he sees dollar signs.

> The White House Sees Only Dollar Signs in the Arctic

[The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/18/opinion/the-white-house-sees-only-dollar-signs-in-the-arctic.html)

> Twista Sees Dollar Signs on 'Stackin Paper': Premierete

https://www.zerchoo.com/music/twista-sees-dollar-signs-on-stackin-paperpremiere/

> Law firm sees dollar signs in drone technology

https://finance-commerce.com/2014/08/law-firm-sees-dollar-signs-in-drone-technology/